# 8.22 Python IT17: Replacement words

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so, I've been trying to figure out this Python 3 Programming task for school, and I can't seem to get it to work.
Here the Prompt for the question

> Write a program that replaces words in a sentence. The input begins
> with word replacement pairs (original and replacement). The next line
> of input is the sentence where any word on the original list is
> replaced.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids The automobile
> manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile
> doesn't already have one.
>
> the output is:
>
> The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already
> have one.
>
> You can assume the original words are unique.

Here's my current code/attempt:

```
replaceList = input()
a1 = replaceList.split()

sentence = input()
for i in sentence:
    i = int(i)
    output = sentence.replace(a1[i], a1[i+1])
print(output)
```

Comment: How do you know when the replacement pairs end and when the text you want to modify starts?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this way (python 3):

```py
# read first line input
pairs = input().split()

# split to originals and replacements
originals = pairs[::2]
replacements = pairs[1::2]

# read the sentence
sent = input()

# replace all words
for org, repl in zip(originals, replacements):
    sent = sent.replace(org, repl)

# print the new sentence
print(sent)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did this:

```
input_list = input().split()
keys = input_list[0::2]
sentence = input().split()
sentence2 = []
for i in sentence:
    if i in keys:
        sentence2.append(input_list[input_list.index(i)+1])
    else:
        sentence2.append(i)

for x in sentence2: 
    if sentence2.index(x) == len(sentence2)-1:
        print(x)
    else:
        print (x, end = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for a while too, this is how I was attempting to complete it but the output format is not correct according to the lab.

```
def main():
replacement_pairs = input()
replacement_pairs = replacement_pairs.split()
original = []
replacement = []
for i in range(len(replacement_pairs)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        original.append(replacement_pairs[i])
    else:
        replacement.append(replacement_pairs[i])
sentence = input()
sentence = sentence.split()
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    for j in range(len(original)):
        if(sentence[i] == original[j]):
            sentence[i] = replacement[j]
    print(sentence[i], end=' ')
    
if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

If i print(sentence[i]) each indices is on their own line, and if i add the space end=' ' then each indices has a blank behind it, sadly the lab wants a space between each indices and a new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

If you really insist on using a list, you can use a pair of the list in a list to store the word and the replacement pairs. However, this is not a common practice that can lead to errors in future developments.

```
# Word pairs to replace
pairs_replace = [["automobile", "car"], ["manufacturer", "maker"], ["children", "kids"]]

# Split the sentence
sentence = "The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.".split()


for i in range(len(sentence)):
    
    for j in range(len(pairs_replace)):
        
        if sentence[i] == pairs_replace[j][0]:
            
            sentence[i] = pairs_replace[j][1]
            
           
output = " ".join(sentence)   

print(output)
```

Output : The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.

I personally approach this problem using a dictionary since you can have a key, value relationship.

```
# Dict of key (word) and value (word to replace)
pairs_replace_dict = {"automobile": "car", "manufacturer": "maker", "children": "kids"}

# Split the sentence
sentence = "The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.".split()

for i in range(len(sentence)):

    for key, value in pairs_replace_dict.items():

        if sentence[i] == key:

            sentence[i] = value

output = " ".join(sentence)

print(output)
```

Output : The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# say pairs but just a list: ['automobile', 'car', 'manufacturer', 'maker', 'children', 'kids']  
# if you really want to pair them at this moment, dictionary may be better
pairs = input().split()

# no need to split the sentence string
sentence = input()

# the last argument of range is the step argument, use to set increment of the numbers  
for i in range(0,len(pairs),2):
    # the loop replaces pairs[i] with pairs[i+1] first, then with step argument 2,
    # it replace pairs[i+2] with [i+3] instead of pairs[i+1] with [i+2] and so on
    sentence = sentence.replace(pairs[i],pairs[i+1])
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. a bit jank perhaps, but it worked:

```py
user_list = input().split()
user_sentence = input()
replace_dict = {}

#convert first input to dict
while len(user_list) != 0:
    for key in user_list:
        replace_dict[user_list[0]] = user_list[1]
        user_list.pop(0)
        user_list.pop(0) 

for orig, replace in replace_dict.items():
    user_sentence = user_sentence.replace(orig, replace)
        
        
print(user_sentence)
```